# Even though I correctly prepare a form, I can't upload an image succesully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to convert  an image from png to jpg but the image I uploaded couldn't be recognized as image but a string

### generated html based on erb

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/funds/withdraw" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="" placeholder="amount" class="form-control form-group">
   </div>
   <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" value="" placeholder="address" class="form-control form-group">
   </div>
   <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
   <input type="submit" name="commit" value="done" class="btn btn-large bg-info" data-disable-with="done">
```

### form

```
     <%= form_tag(funds_withdraw_path,{multipart:true,method: :get})do %>
      <div class="input-group">
     <%= text_field_tag :amount,"",placeholder:"amount",class: 'form-control form-group'%>
     </div>
   <div class="input-group">
    <%= text_field_tag :address,"",placeholder:"address", class: 'form-control form-group'%>
  </div>
  <%=file_field_tag :image%>
  <%= submit_tag "done",class: "btn btn-large bg-info" %>
  <% end %>
```

### controller

```
 ZBar::Image.from_jpeg(to_jpg(params[:image])).process  if params[:image].present?

 def to_jpg(image)
    image = Magick::Image.from_blob(image.read).shift
    puts image.format
    image.format = 'JPG'
   return image
 end
```

### error

```
     undefined method `read' for "qrcode.png":String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multipart forms can't be submitted via GET, you'll have to use POST:

```
<%= form_tag funds_withdraw_path, multipart: true, method: :post do %>
```

When you use GET, the params just end up in the URL, which cannot store a file.